# What is the probability of choosing real numbers over two intervals and them being equal?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You are given two intervals $[0,n_1]$ and $[0,n_2]$. What is the probability that **real number** chosen independently from both the intervals will be equal?

Comment: What density are you choosing with respect to?

Comment: I think the probability is $0$.

Comment: There is one case where the probability is $1$ instead: when $n_1=n_2=0$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually the probability of two independent events is the product of the probability of each event. So the answer depends mostly on your choice of probability distributions.

If you are using *any* distribution that is continuous, the probability is exactly $0$.

Intuitively, this is because there are just too many real numbers on any non-zero interval. There are so many that the probability of selecting a particular one is exactly $0$. So selecting the same twice in a row is just as unlikely.

More formally, the probabilities are obtained by integrating a probability density function $p_1(x)$ over an interval. The function is non-negative and it has the property:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{n_1}p_1(x)dx=1
\end{equation}
The probability of selecting a real in an interval $[a,b]\subset[0,n_1]$ is then given by:
\begin{equation}
\mbox{Prob}(x\in[a,b])=\int_a^{b}p_1(x)dx
\end{equation}
You can see now that, given a real $x_0 \in [0,n_1]$ we have:
\begin{equation}
\mbox{Prob}(x = x_0)=\mbox{Prob}(x\in[x_0,x_0])=\int_{x_0}^{x_0}p_1(x)dx=0
\end{equation}
This is valid for all *continuous distributions*.

If your distribution is *discrete* however, this is another story.

Comment: Nice answer! This makes sense to me, and you certainly backed your claims with valid reasoning.

Comment: And for computable numbers?

Comment: @Nogueira, do you mean picking a computable number from an equiprobable distribution on all the computable numbers? By my understanding, there is a countable infinity of such numbers, so the chance of picking one out of all of them is $0$, just like picking up one natural number at random from all of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: A bounded set of computable numbers $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 5):

If $X\sim\mathcal U[0,n_1]$ and $Y\sim\mathcal U[0,n_2]$ are independent random variables, then the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is uniform over the rectangle
$$R = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: 0\leqslant x\leqslant n_1, 0\leqslant y\leqslant n_2 \}.$$
For any Borel set $A\subset R$, it follows that $\mathbb P((X,Y)\in A)$ is the area of $A$. In other words, the probability measure $\mathbb P\circ(X,Y)^{-1}$ is 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure restricted to $R$. Assuming without loss of generality that $n_1\leqslant n_2$, the set $\{X=Y\}$ is the line segment
$$L=\{(x,x): 0\leqslant x\leqslant n_1\}. $$
It is clear that the area of a line segment is zero. Therefore the probability is zero.